# Vim: Start Regular Expression match from Beginning of Visual Selection

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to use the vim plugin, [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular), to align some misformatted CSS code. Unfortunately, I can't quite seem to grasp how to start the match at the beginning of a visual selection in Vim. Here's some example code:

```
                       color: #a8a8a8;font-family: Helvetica;                                                       

                       color: #d0d0d0;                                                                              
                       font-weight: normal; background-color: inherit; font-size: 13px !important;                  

        background-color: inherit;                                                                                                                             
                             width: 16px; min-width: 16px; display: inline-block; margin-right: 2ex; margin-left: 2px; 
               text-align: center; height: 0; line-height: .5ex; padding-top: 1ex;                          
       background: transparent;
```

My attempt at trying to left align  to the start of the visual block selection hasn't yet succeeded, and I'm wondering where exactly I went wrong:

```
'<,'>Tabularize /\%V\s\+\zs\%V/
```

That is, in the visual selection, match any whitespace and then start the match. That should go up to the first word character and left align there, but I don't think Tabularize recognizes the visual block selection. Also, `\%V` has no notion of `^` and breaks the regex every time. The combination `^\%V` has also failed me.

Any suggestions as to how to quickly format and align to the start of the visual block selection in vim?

Comment: Can you describe how you're defining the visual block selection? For instance, the column number it's starting and the one it's ending in your example.

Comment: @abatishchev: Rollback. The purpose of this question is exactly to know how to align that text using Vim. And though it's related to CSS, it's just related. Any text could be used, so it is better to leave the tag alone. There isn't much to see here by CSS tag watchers.

Comment: @sidyll: You're right. Sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Tabular to do that. Anyway, if you want to use it, do a simple:

```
:'<,'>Tab /^\s\+
```

You don't need a block selection here. By the way, it won't make much sense to work with Tabular and block selections. These are useful when things are already aligned.

But you should be able to align these lines by selecting in line-wise mode with <kbd>V</kbd> and then just hit <kbd>=</kbd>. Alternatively, use a motion like <kbd>=</kbd><kbd>8</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> and avoid the visual selection.